# Brexit: Interactive Brokers vs Firstrade

Tags: european-union, interactive-brokers, brexit

How come Interactive Brokers (IB) needs a UK subsidiary to service EU customers, while other brokers like [Firstrade](https://www.firstrade.com) don’t? Now that Brexit is about to happen, IB will open other subsidiaries in the EU and the investment guarantee goes down from $500k to $20k. Since Firstrade doesn’t operate through subsidiaries, it doesn’t appear to have this problem. Am I missing something? Why does IB resort to subsidiaries?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking or what your complaint is.  What difference does it make to you if you trade through a subsidiary or a parent company? Is there inferior trade execution?  Higher commissions?  As for investment guarantee, SIPC insurance is a U.S. law and covers $500k.  Account insurance in other countries is subject to their jurisdiction.

Comment: The difference is the investment guarantee. A huge problem since 20k is very little. I wonder why they are doing this, what is the advantage for them to have this structure? Clearly, it’s a negative for the customers.

Comment: It’s funny, after reading around, that introducing broker Zackstrade is using IB as a clearing agent, yet Zackstrade is domiciled in the US and is thus covered by SIPC, while IB Europe, as an introducing broker, after Brexit, won’t be covered. I just don’t understand why IB needs EU domiciled subsidiaries, a clear negative for EU customers.

Comment: IB carries much [more coverage](https://www1.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=2334&p=acc&conf=am)  than the $500k SIPC limit.  In Canada, you'd be covered by $1 million via CIPF.  I'm an IB customer in the U.S. so I have no clue what they offer in the EU.  It does seem odd that the limit would only be $20k. Are you sure that amount is correct?

Comment: Yep, it hasn’t changed since 1998! (with a couple of exceptions, Spain and France) The IB Q&A section on Brexit confirms the new limit. I am currently looking for new brokers that have a better guarantee against bankruptcy, but they are very small, such as Firstrade, Zackstrade, Swissquote, Tradestation. I wished I wasn't born in the EU.